# Joining two tables on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two SQL Server tables: `ORDR` (orders) and `RDR1` (order's items). I'm trying to create a report which shows:

- DocEntry, CardName, DocDueDate: info about the order
- pTot: total amount of items in the order
- ItemCode: item's code (any of them, only one is needed)
- Dscription: item's name

My last attempt was:

```
SELECT 
    dbo.ORDR.DocEntry, dbo.ORDR.CardName, dbo.ORDR.DocDueDate,
    SUM(dbo.RDR1.Quantity) AS pTot,
    dbo.RDR1.ItemCode,
    dbo.RDR1.Dscription
FROM 
    dbo.ORDR 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.RDR1 ON dbo.ORDR.DocEntry = dbo.RDR1.DocEntry
GROUP BY 
    dbo.ORDR.DocEntry, dbo.ORDR.CardName, dbo.ORDR.DocDueDate, 
    dbo.RDR1.ItemCode, dbo.RDR1.Dscription
```

Items' code/name in one order are very similar so I need only the first RDR1's record associated to that order

I have 2 problems:

1. I'm getting one row for each RDR1 record
2. `pTot` is not summing the amount of items

Can you show me how to join these tables properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` to get the first `RDR1` item for each `ORDR` and `SUM OVER` to get the total amount of items.

```
SELECT
    o.DocEntry,
    o.CardName,
    o.DocDueDate,
    r.pTot,
    r.ItemCode,
    r.Dscription
FROM dbo.ORDR o
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DocEntry ORDER BY ItemCode),
        pTot = SUM(Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY DocEntry)
    FROM dbo.RDR1   
) r
    ON r.DocEntry = o.DocEntry
WHERE r.rn = 1
```

Additionally, you might want to use meaningful table aliases to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposed solution.

```
SELECT 
    [rowno] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DocEntry ORDER BY ItemCode),
    O.DocEntry, 
    O.CardName, 
    O.DocDueDate,
    SUM(Quantity) AS pTot,
    O.ItemCode,
    O.Dscription
INTO #TEMP_ORDER
FROM dbo.ORDR O
INNER JOIN dbo.RDR1 R
    ON O.DocEntry = dbo.RDR1.DocEntry
GROUP BY O.DocEntry, O.CardName, O.DocDueDate, R.ItemCode, R.Dscription

SELECT 
    DocEntry, 
    CardName, 
    DocDueDate,
    pTot,
    ItemCode,
    Dscription
FROM #TEMP_ORDER
WHERE roWno = 1

DROP TABLE #TEMP_ORDER
```